# Apache Kafka relation between partition and stream

Tags: apache-kafka

1. What is the relation between the partitions of a topic and the streams which could be created using Java api?
2. What is the rationale behind having the API like

   ```
    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>>  consumerMap = _consumerConnector.createMessageStreams(topicVsPartitionCountMap);
   ```

   instead of simply having it like

   ```
   List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> consumerStreams = _consumerConnector.createMessageStreams(partitionCountForTopic);
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is not actually a map of topicName to partitionCount but rather
   to the number of streams you would like. Each stream provides an
   endless iterator and therefore consumes one thread by intended use
   (you can always combine two on one thread but then you might as well
   create less streams to begin with).

   The relationship to the partition is that one partition always
   provides data to the same stream. Therefore, within that
   stream/thread you are provided the same ordering guarantees as is
   modeled within your kafka partition. So, if event A happens before
   event B in partition X, and, partition X and partition Y both stream
   to stream 1, then, event A is guaranteed to be processed before
   event B if stream 1 is processed in order.
2. I think this is just the design decision they chose (they are essentially identical, you can achieve the same with both). The only other thing I can think of is that every call to `createMessageStreams` reaches out to
   ZooKeeper and Kafka to set up the stream regardless of how many
   streams you fetch and therefore there is less overhead when you
   fetch multiple in the same call.